# If all images on page return an error redirect?

Tags: javascript, image, redirect

How can I make so if all the images on the page are broken/don't exist javascript will redirect to another page?

I want to use this in an image gallery type script.

Comment: Using pure javascript? Do you happen to be using a javascript framework such as jQuery, prototype etc?

Comment: I would prefer pure javascript but i could use jQuery or other framework if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this script a try:

```
var imgCount = 0, imgErrorCount = 0;

function onImgError(increment) {
    if(increment) {
        imgErrorCount++;
    }
    if(imgCount > 0 && imgCount == imgErrorCount) {
        location = '/url-to-redirect';
    }
}
$(function(){
    imgCount = $('img').length;
    onImgError(false);
});
```

And for every img element:

```
<img src="..." onerror="onImgError(true);" />
```

Comment: @TheScrumMeister Nice, but why don't you assign the `onerror` handler directly in JS? Like so: `$('img').each(function() { $(this).get().onerror = function() { onImgError(true); };});`

Comment: It didn't seem to work. Edit: `$(function(){`
**Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined**

Comment: @Jacob: That's too late. Once the img is inserted into the DOM tree, it starts loading immediately. So it may already have failed when you try to add the onerror handler

Comment: Opps forgot to add my jquery! My bad. Thanks alot!

Comment: @jacob-relkin `$('img')` will not include future images added to the dom, and if you call it on the bottom of the page, some images may have already errord out. `$('img').live()` doesn't seem to work.